# Accessing Hard Drive connected to modem

Tags: networking, external-hdd, modem

I have just installed Ubuntu and I need to see the hard disc drive that is connected to my router.

I have an EE router latest version.

Edit - I have looked in other locations and there is nothing in there...

I am VERY new to Ubuntu so please can you give me easy steps on how to map the drive.

Thanks in advance

Kriss :)

Comment: Edit your question to include your modem's owner manual section on the topic.

Comment: I had already checked that and nothing just tried the command for my modem and it came up with an error : Falied to retrieve share list from server:Server caused connection abort

Comment: When you had it working in Windows, did you need to download a driver or an app/software in Windows to make it work? It is difficult to troubleshoot problems with a hardware (router in this case) without having it or knowing anything about it. If you can find the router's manual / user guide online add a link to it in your question.

Comment: I have another idea: instead of `smb://192.168.x.1`, try `ftp://192.168.x.1`.

Comment: See [this manual](https://static.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/Archer_C7_V3_UG_US.pdf) for example.

Comment: It was fine with windows as it has an actual network... I have it just put into the laptop for now and will see what I can sort out... :)